# I copied files from my old computer onto a drive I had encrypted on my new computer, and now I can't see them

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, encryption

I did something dumb. I'm setting up a new computer, and I did a clean install with an encrypted `/home` partition set up on its own new SSD -- I clicked the checkbox during installation to encrypt the home folder, and didn't change anything else after that.

Once I had installed, I took out the `/home` SSD and plugged it into my old computer to copy all my files over -- almost 1TB worth, took half a day of copying with quite a bit of effort to weed through old cruft that I don't need any more.

But when I put the SSD back in the new computer, it doesn't see the files -- I assume that the drive was not mounted with encryption when I was copying the files, so they were copied unencrypted, and the drive is mounted encrypted in the new computer, so they don't show up?

1. Is there any way to get the files to reappear while the drive is mounted in the new computer? I care less about encryption at this point than about being able to access the files, so a solution that turns off encryption is fine with me.
2. If that is not possible, what steps would I need to take to redo the file copying process and do it right this time?

I have done a fair bit of searching but so far haven't been able to find anyone else as dumb as me. :)

Edit: output of `/etc/fstab` (on new computer):

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
UUID=6de3bb08-9d43-49f0-b7b7-78cb7aaa1b28   /        ext4   noatime,errors=remount-ro  0       1
UUID=13fecad0-8105-4320-bf34-7d348d596ba9   /home    ext4   noatime,errors=remount-ro  0       1
#UUID=5938b5a9-af54-47e7-8e5a-68189932d06f   none    swap   sw                         0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1                       none    swap   sw                         0       0
```

And output of `mount -l`:

```
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=16416252k,nr_inodes=4104063,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=3294296k,mode=755)
/dev/nvme0n1p1 on / type ext4 (rw,noatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids,release_agent=/run/cgmanager/agents/cgm-release-agent.pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset,clone_children)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb,release_agent=/run/cgmanager/agents/cgm-release-agent.hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event,release_agent=/run/cgmanager/agents/cgm-release-agent.perf_event)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=30,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=25070)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw)
/dev/sda on /home type ext4 (rw,noatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered) [Data]
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,relatime)
cgmfs on /run/cgmanager/fs type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=100k,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=3294296k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
/home/.ecryptfs/arvana/.Private on /home/arvana type ecryptfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=287594d3d10316bd,ecryptfs_sig=f1e3b15ce0ca0a66,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_unlink_sigs)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
```

Comment: +1 for insight. Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/950338/edit) and provide the output of `cat /etc/fstab` and `mount -l`, each in a code block (`{}` button).

Answer (score 0):

1. Not that I'm aware of. I'm not sure what happened to the files you copied as you didn't specify the full path of your target and `ecryptfs-setup-private` creates a ~/Private directory to contain encrypted information. You can see this `/home/.ecryptfs/arvana/.Private` in your output from `mount -l`.
2. To redo the file copying process correctly, Insure that the drive is either:

A) prepared and mounted without encryption on both systems.

or

B) prepared and mounted with the exact same encryption [ecryptfs](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/ecryptfs.html) on both the source and target systems.

The [ecryptfs-utils package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ecryptfs-utils&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) has several useful utilities to assist you in this endeavor.

After initial setup utilizing `ecryptfs-setup-private` I would expect `ecryptfs-mount-private` and `ecryptfs-umount-private` which mount and unmount a user's ~/Private directory to be useful to you.

I would expect to ensure that the following files were identical on both the source and target.

`/root/.ecryptfsrc`
`/root/.ecryptfs/sig-cache.txt`

For more information on `ecryptfs` including some details regarding `/mnt/usb/passwd_file.txt` and `/etc/fstab` I don't have the time to include here, see the sources below.

Sources:

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/ecryptfs.html

https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ecryptfs-utils/+questions?field.sort=by+relevancy&field.actions.search=Search&field.status=Answered&field.status=Solved